# Trying to parse all results from z-lib to build a database of book titles

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a list of all available books in z-library, but results are only provided though a search term and I want the titles for all books.

Also, queries only feature 10 pages of 50 results per page, 500 in total. Doing an empty search using only a spacebar renders top 500 most popular books.

I intend to use Selenium and Python but I can't get around to accessing the entire list of books.

https://book4you.org/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very abstractive for this site. Please add more details, snippets of code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get all the books data by Selenium or web scraper on such site since these tools will only present you a results displayed by GUI for a specific key search query.
This maybe can be performed via some API GET protocol request to get ALL the data from the DB, however we can not know if that possible or not until we know all the API requests available for that specific site.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I am trying to see what I can find through going through the homepage html again and running some tests in Insomnia.

Comment: OK, please let me know if you find any solution with Selenium / scraper. I don't think there are such, but in case there are - it would be interesting to know.